# win_ros 'rosversion' not recognized

Tags: ros, rosversion, win-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use win_ros and have installed the SDK as outlined here:

http://wiki.ros.org/win_ros/hydro/Msvc%20SDK

Problem is that after calling the batch file, when I try to launch roscore, I get this error:

```
`rosversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

and it errors out. I've tried both groovy and hydro versions, and I get the same error. Anyone know what's going on?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/92496/win_ros-%27rosversion%27-not-recognized/) by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 452 on 2013-10-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a errant space in my PATH environment variable; all is well now.

---

Originally posted by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) with karma: 452 on 2013-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0